# Get aggregated result daily in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would need to handle a very complex SQL problem:
the input data looks like:

```
device_id | install_time
```

AND I would need to get daily installs and re_installs(means this device has already had a `install_time` before today), how could I quickly generate this table result?

Here is a sample result:

```
id1 | 08/24/2020
id1 | 08/23/2020
id1 | 08/22/2020
id2 | 08/22/2020
id3 | 08/23/2020
id3 | 08/22/2020
```

the result should be

```
date | install | re_install
08/22/2020 | 3 | 0
08/23/2020 | 2 | 2
08/24/2020 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: Can you please make it simple by specifying input and possible output result , so that we can give you proper answer. Thanks!

Comment: How's this version sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select install_time::date,
       count(*) as num_installs,
       count(*) filter (where seqnum > 1) as num_reinstalls
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by install_time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by install_time::date
```